# Is it ethical to be a co-author on every paper that comes out of your group? Especially if these leads to authoring hundreds of papers per year?

Tags: publications

I just learned about a professor whose group published [300 papers in 1 year](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ni4ai.jpg). I found that the professor is an author or co-author on every single one of them.

I understand the argument that in some fields, PIs deserve to be the last author on all papers from their group. I am not soliciting opinions about the reasonableness of this practice in general. I imagine that in most cases, the professor can reasonably track all the papers, and there is no issue.

But certainly there is no way a PI can make an intellectual contribution to 300 papers per year, right? Does an ethical issue arise when the supervisor's group is so large that the supervisor is getting authorship on papers they are barely aware of?

Comment: This doesn't really seem like a question that can be answered in any meaningful way, but that nature article was kind of interesting.

Comment: "What are your insights?" really isn't a good type of question for this site.

Comment: I suppose if you're second or third supervisor to loads of PhD students, and you do nothing else but review draft papers written by those students, you can probably make a contribution that just about warrants co-authorship in less than one full working day per paper, and 300 per year is therefore possible.  But that doesn't strike me as a very enjoyable or fulfilling way to do academia, nor as likely to make you very popular with colleagues who are left with more than their fair share of admin work and undergrad teaching as a result.

Comment: This professor knows more emojis than I do.

Comment: The link OP includes does not say that this is from a single professor, but from the "Biomedicine Laboratory, Department of Life Sciences,
Presidency University." If this is a large lab, then this is possible. If the head of the department insists to be included as author on each paper, then he may have 300 publications in a year, but that doesn't mean anything.

Comment: Big boats carry lots of people.

Comment: I took a stab at editing the question to bring it more in line with what we can answer here.

Comment: @cag51, unfortunately you have changed the meaning dramatically.

Comment: Maybe it is hidden somewhere that I missed, but the image doesn't make the claim that I can see that someone claimed authorship on all the papers. The "we" could well be an entire department with several independent groups of authors.

Comment: @Buffy - actually, the original version said: "(Yes, he is on all 300, I checked his Facebook)."

Comment: @Buffy Let’s leave to the OP to decide whether they are OK with the change or not. On a side note, that’s why it’s better to close as soon as possible off-topic or unclear questions, to avoid such kind of questions being answered before the necessary adjustments.

Comment: @Buffy - actually, the more I review it, the more I find your objection puzzling. To me, this is an absolutely _exemplary_ edit that transforms a rant into an interesting question _without_ greatly changing the meaning. If you think that the question was unsalvageable and no edits should be attempted, then it's very curious that you would post an answer. Anyway, I deliberately didn't hammer the question back open, so the normal process can play out.

Comment: @cag51, I answered the original version. I think the answer is still valid, as, in some circumstances there isn't an ethical issue. I don't deny that there could be one in some other circumstances. But do we really want this to be a judgement or condemnation of the practice in some fields of the PI always being last author? I know some feel that, in itself, is unethical, but I withhold judgement as it isn't my field.

Comment: @cag51 Hum, that was a good edit. Academia.SE is unironically becoming my writing skills improvement coach.

Comment: Thanks. Buffy had a point though; we don't want an opinion poll about whether a field's common practices are a good idea. Took a stab at improving further.

Comment: This is the Google Scholar page of the University. https://scholar.google.com/citations?view_op=view_org&hl=en&org=6760821013347586605. I doubt that his name is on all of the papers

Comment: Who cares?  Personally I'm disimpressed by this kind of publication record; I assume someone who publishes so much could easily make a bigger contribution to their field by concentrating their work on fewer, more significant pieces of work.  If this person is subject to some perverse incentives that encourage this kind of behavior, then we should work on changing the incentives.

Answer (score 3):

It is impossible to make a "significant" contribution to 300 papers a year. In my opinion this is scientific misconduct. See for example the "The White Bull effect" https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC1734216/

Comment: The threshold for significant contributions is much less than 300 papers/year.  Else this person would already be recognized as a genius.  Of course the solution is well-known: restrict funding applications so individual applicants can list at most 10 or 15 or 20 papers over some set timeframe in their CV, thereby removing the incentive to co-author 300 papers a year.

Comment: As much as I find this example baffling, the standards of contribution may be low. If you sit down in a meeting on Monday and say "try X primer protein", by Tuesday it solves an issue 10 research groups were having, they each quickly churn out a paper (common in COVID times in biomed), and by the next week you have your name on 10 papers, all for less than half an hour of work. In more regular parts of academia, the technique would likely be published as a separate (highly-cited) paper, but it also does not always make sense. This case (IMHO) is bad, but then how does one set a threshold?

Comment: How does 168 in a year sound? That's three a week, or so? The reason I ask is simply that Erdos managed that many in 1966. ... but only around 65 in 1958, the next highest year.

Comment: [This article](https://www.nature.com/articles/d41586-023-00016-1) seems relevant.

Answer (score 2):

It probably wouldn't be possible in some fields like mathematics, but in other fields it might be entirely appropriate as the criteria for authorship varies.

In particular a PI of a large and well-funded research group who has hands in a lot of pies simultaneously might show up as (usually) "last" author on all of the work done by the group. They make the research possible by drawing in funds and approving research areas of students and postdocs.

Note also that in some areas like high energy physics a given paper might have hundreds of authors all of whom were essential to carrying out the research. All those people likely work on several things simultaneously.

And, in almost every system there will be numeric outliers. Special conditions might apply that wouldn't in almost every case. Someone with a huge circle of collaboration, for example, who is able to spark a-ha moments in their colleagues, breaking logjams. I think Erdős must have been like that in math, but not at the 300/year level.

To answer the headline question, if it were "gift authorship" then it wouldn't be appropriate, but the individual circumstances matter. One can't expect that the number of papers per year is normally distributed.

---

Note, of course, that the linked image says "*we published*", not giving context as to who *we* are. If that was the head of a department, writing for the entire faculty and students, it would be entirely possible, not even especially remarkable in a large department.

Comment: I can get your idea, but still, 300 papers in 1 year? This stinks. It makes me wonder about having bots help writing (as this professor actually mentioned he wrote 100 book chapters that year).

Comment: @Jef, one would need to look at the journals. I don't know whether they are reputable or not, but, again, the distribution likely has a long tail. And they are unlikely to be sole authorship in any case. I doubts that it is bots, though.

Comment: Seems possible that a large biomedical lab might well have gotten some 300 papers (perhaps many short notes) out on Covid - folks were doing a _LOT_ of work...

Comment: @Jef, possibly if you code-up the bots yourself, and train them yourself, then you get credit for anything they write. :)

Comment: @Jef We have had these biobots in academia for a loooong time, they are called students.

Comment: I voted to reopen